# The regex in my python class is always returning false

Tags: python, regex

```
class MyTest:

    a = re.compile('abc')

    def testthis(self, fname):
        print fname
        if self.a.match(fname):
            return 'yes'
        else:
            return 'no'
```

If I pass `'testabc'` to `testthis()` then it prints `no`. If I change the regex to `.*abc` then it prints yes. What's going on? Is it trying to match against the whole string?

Comment: Well, what are some of the things you're passing it?

Comment: It should match any `fname` containing `abc`. Show us what it's failing on. (If you want it to only match strings *ending in* abc, put `$` at the end.)

Comment: Sorry. If the regex is '.*abc' and I pass 'testabc' to it, then it works. If the regex is 'abc' and I pass 'testabc' to it, then it's false. Why is that? I'm familiar with perl regex but it's the first time I'm doing it in python.

Comment: Uh, that's a **completely** different question...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.match) (emphasis mine):

> `re.match(pattern, string[, flags])`
>
> If zero or more characters **at the beginning of string** match the regular expression pattern, return a corresponding MatchObject instance. Return None if the string does not match the pattern; note that this is different from a zero-length match.

Perhaps you wanted `.search()` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Based on a comment you added to your question, you were finding the value `no` printed for this python code:

```
import re
class MyTest:
    a = re.compile('abc')
    def testthis(self, fname):
        print fname
        if self.a.match(fname):
            return 'yes'
        else:
            return 'no'

t = MyTest()
print t.testthis('testabc')
```

This surprised you because it would match in Perl.

That's because with Python, `match` works on the *beginning of the string*, unlike Perl where `m` looks for a match anywhere in the string.  (In Java, it works on the *whole string*.)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a regex `abc` and have it match `testabc`, you have to use `search` instead of `match`. `match` only matches from the beginning of the string; `search` matches anywhere in the string.